# Tandberg XACLI interface : Advantages

Tags: conferencing

I am new to the API provided by [Tandberg in their MXP series Video Conferencing equipment](http://developer.tandberg.com/web/guest/products/codecs/mxp3000). I want to confirm a doubt about the XACLI interface.

As far as I researched into this, XACLI can only do what http or for that matter remote control can do locally. only that one can schedule it using standard OS tools.

So, is there anything more to XACLI interface than being able to do things from remote end? or its just a geekier way to do things?

Comment: A little more background on this would help. There's really not enough information to make heads or tails of whatever it is you're talking about. MXP series of *what*? What do you actually want to do? If its something that turns out not to be specific, it would widen the number of people who could help answer the question.

Comment: i have edited the question. Hope it will clarify things...